# Resetting csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(some_string))

Tags: python, csv

I am using python's csv.DictReader but I am initializing it with a string like this:

```
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(some_string))
```

Is there a way to reset the DictReader's iterator so that I can use it multiple times?  I would rather not re-parse some_string as it can be an expensive operation.

Comment: `L = list(dict_reader)`?

Comment: That creates a list rather than resetting the iterator -- which is probably what I will have to do.  I wonder what the difference in memory footprint will be.

Comment: Try it and find out.  If you can afford to load the giant string in memory (as you do now), you can probably afford to keep the dict in memory too.  And if you can't, there's always numpy.ndarray.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As you probably already know, the initialization:

```
dict_reader = csv.DictReader(StringIO.StringIO(some_string))
```

does not actually read anything from the `StringIO.StringIO` instance. The `dict_reader` starts reading only when you start grabbing rows from it and it reads the input line-by-line. In other words, it will only read as many lines as the number of rows you ask from it. Here is an example:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import csv
try:
    from StringIO import StringIO   # Python 2.x
except ImportError:
    from io import StringIO         # Python 3.x

test_string = """name,value
foo,1
bar,2
"""

string_io = StringIO(test_string)
# 
# Position is 0 i.e. the beginning of the string.
# 
print("Position: {}".format(string_io.tell()))

dict_reader = csv.DictReader(string_io)
#
# Position is still 0. Nothing has been read.
#
print("Position: {}".format(string_io.tell()))
#
# Now we start reading from string_io
#
for row in dict_reader:
    print(row)
    #
    # Position increases every time you read 
    # a row using dict_reader.
    #
    print("Position: {}".format(string_io.tell()))
```

This will print:

```
Position: 0
Position: 0
{'name': 'foo', 'value': '1'}
Position: 17
{'name': 'bar', 'value': '2'}
Position: 23
```

At the end of all this the current position in `string_io` will point to the end of the string. So, even if you could reuse `dict_reader` you will have to seek to the beginning of `string_io` first and start scanning it all over again. In fact, you can do the following after the above code:

```
string_io.seek(0)
for row in dict_reader:
    print(row)
    print("Position: {}".format(string_io.tell()))
```

This `for` loop will print the following:

```
{'name': 'name', 'value': 'value'}
Position: 11
{'name': 'foo', 'value': '1'}
Position: 17
{'name': 'bar', 'value': '2'}
Position: 23
```

Notice that `dict_reader` now treats the first line of `string_io` as data rather than using it to decide the names of the fields. Furthermore, `dict_reader` itself does not keep all the lines that it has scanned. Once a row is passed to you, it is no longer available via `dict_reader`. You can see this from definition of `csv.DictReader.next()` in [csv.py](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/csv.py?view=markup) and `Reader_iternext()` in [_csv.c](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Modules/_csv.c?view=markup). So, you are better off storing the rows somewhere yourselves as suggested in the comments.